# Parse server Java script Cloud code Error : [TypeError: A ParseQuery must be constructed with a ParseObject or class name.]

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to run a cloud code function to query the server and get a list of users from a class called ROOMS. I want to then use the value "USER" of the objects that are found to run another query in which I send push notifications to those users.

Here is the code that I have so far, I am used to writing in SWIFT so I am not too good at javascript

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("chatNoti", function(request,response){

  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.ROOMS);
  userQuery.equalTo("roomName",request.params.roomname);


  var message = request.params.message;
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.containedIn("user","USER",userQuery);   

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data : { 
      alert: message,
      "badge": 1,
    }
    }, {
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    response.success(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    response.error(error.message)
    },
  useMasterKey: true

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Parse.ROOMS does not exist try replacing with “ROOMS” if thst’s The name of your collection. Note that collection names are case sensitive.